# AngularJS Table Rendering Slow in IE but fast in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, performance, internet-explorer

I'm hoping someone could give me some insight on the following issue I'm having. I have a table that when rendered in Chrome it's usable without any issues. However, in IE the page is completely unusable and slow. it locks up. The page itself uses more memory than I would like but in chrome it seems the GC frees up the memory after you navigate away from the page and in IE it does not.

Here is the code for the table rendering

```
<table class="qactable col-md-offset-0 topmargin text-tanblue">
    <thead>
        <tr>     
            <th class="rotate"></th>           
            <th class="rotate" ng-repeat="item in availability">
                <div><span>{{::item.Date | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span></div> 
            </th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="area in areas track by $index" class="qactr">
            <td class="qactd">
                {{area}}
            </td>               
            <td ng-repeat="item in availability" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div style="height:100%;" 
                    uib-tooltip="{{::blah.AreaName}} {{::item.Date | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"  
                    ng-disabled="blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits == 0" 
                    ng-click="goToFind(blah.AreaName,item.Date,blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits)" 
                    class="qactd"                                   
                    ng-class="{red: blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits == 0, yellow: blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits > 0 && blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits < 2, green: blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits >= 2}"                 
                    ng-repeat="blah in item.items" 
                    ng-if="blah.AreaName == area">
                    {{::blah.NumberOfAvailableUnits}}
                </div
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

This isn't something that can be fixed with pagination as the table is displayed on one page.

as you can see I tried to use one way binding (I think) to help alleviate the issue but it did not make a difference.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of both browsers? What version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: I'm using the latest of both browsers. IE 11